# Xamarin Forms iOS Renderer for Facebook Audience Network

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, facebook-audience-network

I had developed a cross platform app using Xamarin Forms which is working fine. Now, I want to display ads in the app so I read some articles and have gone through some youtube vidoes **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fENpVR0rlO8**. Most of the videos only show you how to implement custom renderer for FAN in Andriod but I have not found any artcile or video that can guide me how to implement custom renderer for **FAN in iOS**.

Can any one please suggest what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at codes in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179968/how-to-use-facebook-audience-in-xamarin-forms) would help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I had already looked into that but that didn't work so far :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. Here is what I had done in order to make it work. May be it can help some one like me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Text;
using Facebook.AudienceNetwork;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using VRunTracker;
using VRunTracker.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FacebookAdsControl), typeof(FacebookAdRenderer))]
namespace VRunTracker.iOS
{
    public class FacebookAdRenderer : ViewRenderer<FacebookAdsControl,UIView>
    {
        public FacebookAdRenderer()
        {

        }

        private FacebookAdsControl AdsControl => (FacebookAdsControl) Element;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FacebookAdsControl> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (AdsControl == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
            AdView adView = new AdView(AdsControl.PlacementId, AdSizes.BannerHeight50, rootVC);
            adView.LoadAd();
            SetNativeControl(adView);


        }
    }
}
```

Hope that can help others.
Riy

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).