# Integrating Facebook Audience Network in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, facebook-audience-network

I have been trying to integrate Facebook Audience Network so as to load native ads in my Xamarin Native iOS application. When I debug my application the code enters method "NativeAdDidFail" and the NSError says "No fill" and No other information is printed in the console.

This is what I have done:

1. Created a resource in business manager and Selected iOS as the target platform.
2. I left out the payment/mediation and app store URL since my app is not published.
3. Added an ad placement for native ads and Added one test device in the Monetization manager by adding my iphones IDFA.
4. Enabled testing, Checked the checkbox for "use real ads", I also clicked on the "choose ad type" **but it doesnt seem to be saved?**
5. Added one test user in business manager and Assigned access to the created property.
6. Downloaded native Facebook app and Enabled tracking in the background for the native facebook app.
7. Logged in on the native app with the email of the test user that I added.
8. Added "SkadNetworkIdentifier" and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist-> v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork & n38lu8286q.skadnetwork
9. Downloaded Xamarin.Facebook.Audiencenetwork.ios

**This is my code:**

```
        AdSettings.SetAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false);
        AdSettings.ClearTestDevices();
        AdSettings.AddTestDevice("74312C38-4958-4187-B385-9FCFE68FRRA9");
        nativeAd = new NativeAd("CAROUSEL_IMG_SQUARE_LINK#611875720420055_511995483752412")
            { Delegate = this };
            nativeAd.LoadAd();

    [Export("nativeAdDidLoad:")]
    public void NativeAdDidLoad(NativeAd nativeAd)
    {

    }

    [Export("nativeAd:didFailWithError:")]
    public void NativeAdDidFail(NativeAd nativeAd, NSError error)
    {
        var errorcode = error.Code;
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NativeAdDidFail)} - Native ad failed to load with error: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
        //AppDelegate.ShowMessage("Native Ad Error", error.LocalizedDescription, NavigationController);
    }

    [Export("nativeAdDidClick:")]
    public void NativeAdDidClick(NativeAd nativeAd) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NativeAdDidClick)} - Native ad was clicked.");

    [Export("nativeAdDidFinishHandlingClick:")]
    public void NativeAdDidFinishHandlingClick(NativeAd nativeAd) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NativeAdDidFinishHandlingClick)} - Native ad did finish click handling.");

    [Export("nativeAdWillLogImpression:")]
    public void NativeAdWillLogImpression(NativeAd nativeAd) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NativeAdWillLogImpression)} - Native ad impression is being captured.");
```

Here's [the tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/testing/platform?__cft__%5B0%5D=AZXrltjw_M6dAIEONKINsrLRB35TFQf5lJz8dqcD71VyZJZJNnWrkWXhRcwbnTAfoDaxjkaABz-BxioydcsNV6l5b-IqjBZD6DKj9R_2NAkKX3p0cj7RqEOuMniIAsSuOi-sy4sDPpOuwQnZCriClU_h&__tn__=R%5D-R) I am trying to follow

According to the [Facebook Audience Network](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/test/checklist-errors/), this could be the possible reasons:

[image]

Comment: this is the 5th variation of this question you've asked in the past week or so without a response.  You may need to accept that SO just doesn't have anyone in the community with relevant experience and you might need to go elsewhere for help.

Comment: Yes I know you are right! I just don't have anyone else to ask. This was my last attempt @Jason

Comment: 1) where do you see this "No Fill" error appear? 2) Is it working with android? 3) Does it print any of the other console text you have in the console? 4) Have you watched this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fENpVR0rlO8 ? 5) Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623460/xamarin-forms-ios-renderer-for-facebook-audience-network ? 6) @Riy do you have any recommendations? 7) Maybe your issue is here "choose ad type"?

Comment: Is your code open source? Can you create a reproducible sample that we can clone and test with?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251544/xamarinforms-facebook-audience-network-ads-not-hav.html Have you seen the repos, videos and tutorials here?

Comment: @Saamer 1) When I debug my application the code enters method "NativeAdDidFail" and the NSError says "No fill" 2) My application is only for iOS right now 3) No other information is printed in the console. 4) No i haven't,  thank you I will check it out! 7) Yes maybe, I choose one and it gets selected but when I close the window it still says "choose ad type".

Comment: @Saamer No it is not open source, I followed this sample: https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/tree/main/Facebook.iOS/samples/FBAudienceNetworkSample, I am not working in Xamarin.Forms but Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: It seems the error is a native error. 1. Are you sure the User is logged into Native Facebook App on Mobile Device?
2. Have you informed Facebook through the setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled flag to not deliver personalized ads via Audience Network?
3. Did you check the settings to see if you have given permission for Facebook to use your activity, to personalize the ads Facebook delivers to that person?
4. Do you have Ad Inventory for current user?
5. Does your testing device have the native Facebook application installed?
6. Did you wait and attempt to make another request after 30 seconds?